# Getting Missing Operator error in This Query in MS access query Design

Tags: sql, ms-access

```
UPDATE Temp1 a 
  SET TimeStamp1 = CASE(
                     WHEN (a.TimeStamp1 IN
                       (SELECT TimeStamp1 
                          FROM a 
                          WHERE a.DealName = 'Disha Rufous' 
                          AND a.DealStep = 'Sent for Risk feedback')
                       - a.TimeStamp1 IN
                       (SELECT TimeStamp1 
                          FROM a 
                          WHERE a.DealName = 'Disha Rufous' 
                          AND a.DealStep = 'De-dupe confirmation received')
                       IS NOT NULL THEN '0' ELSE TimeStamp1 END) 
  WHERE Temp1.DealName = 'dede' 
  AND Temp1.StepName = 'Risk feedback addressed'
```

Error is indicating at `THEN` in `CASE` function.

Answer (score 0):

Your `CASE` is:

```
CASE
    WHEN a IN (X) - a IN (Y) IS NOT NULL
        THEN...
    ELSE ...
END
```

I suppose you can see now why it won't work, you're `WHEN` clause is invalid. `a IN (X)` returns `true` or `false`, it makes no sense to subtract another `true/false` value from it and then to see whether it is null or not.

I'm guessing you want:

```
UPDATE Temp1 a SET TimeStamp1 = CASE 
                                        WHEN a.TimeStamp1 IN(SELECT TimeStamp1 FROM Temp1 WHERE DealName = 'Disha Rufous' AND DealStep = 'Sent for Risk feedback') 
                                            AND a.TimeStamp1 IN(SELECT TimeStamp1 FROM Temp1 WHERE DealName = 'Disha Rufous' AND DealStep = 'De-dupe confirmation received') 
                                            THEN '0'  
                                        ELSE TimeStamp1 
                                END 
WHERE DealName = 'dede' AND StepName = 'Risk feedback addressed'
```

You may need to change the `AND` into `OR` in the `WHEN` clause, depending on your requirements.

Comment: What If I put > or < sign in place of subtraction sign?? And syntax error is happening at the 'THEN' position, what's with that??

Comment: That would still make no sense, what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to check if the difference of those 2 expression > 0 , then condtion

Comment: Can I use `IF` statement?

Comment: Please see further edit, your selects can't refer to the table your updating

Comment: But the missing operator error is occurring at `THEN`.

Comment: What is the datatype of `Timestamp1`?

Comment: Its Date and Time like `12-05-2016 15:22:19`

Comment: `0` is (probably, not too familiar with mysql) not a valid `datetime`, what date do you want to use in the `THEN`? Also see another edit...

Comment: I can use any date for example,  but why is the missing operator error coming? I am doing it in MS Access Query Design tool

Comment: I don't know that design tool. I have to admit I didn't test my code, but far as I know, with last update it should work. Do you still get the same error?